# What regular expression can be used to find negative decimal values in a next file using Notepad++?

Tags: find, decimal, notepad++

I looked online but couldn't find what i needed. I saw people post similar requests here so i joined. I use text file to track money spending and want to be able to find and track specific ones; so i need the regular expressions that lets me find negative numbers of 2/3/4/5 digits (that's 4 different ones) **followed by €** - this is important since order number also appear in that text file, so it won't work without the € in the end. Of course that'll possibly be replace by £/$/else. So the values could be something like -80,45€, -255,55€, -1259,99€,-15000,00€.

Comment: What do you mean with "in a next file"? What does "next" relate to?

Comment: TEXT! Sorry for the typo -.-

Comment: You can edit...

Comment: Too late now? Can't see edit button for FP

Comment: There is an edit link below the question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you can use:

Find: `-\d{2,5},\d\d€`

Explanation:

- `-`: literal hyphen/minus
- `\d`: a digit
- `\d{2,5}`: 2 to 5 digits
- `,`: literal comma
- `\d\d`: two digits
- `€`: literal €

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work, it's not recognized..

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me. Maybe the decimals are optional? Updated that so it also matches without them.

Comment: Well NO they are not optionnal at all..! Because they are missing, the expression now only let me find things such as -20€ which are a rarity as i ALWAYS use ,xx unless forgotten.

Why woud first one (please write it back) wouldn't work for me if working for you..? I have v8.4.2, what's yours? I don't think that could be the reason though..

Comment: I'll give an exemple of what typical line looks like (that may help perhaps) : [Shop/XXX]Order 12345 -  Article1, Article2, Article2 : -xx,xx€ (CARD-1234)

Comment: OK, but I see nothing there what should match according to your requirements. What did you think should match? About decimals: your question said 2/3/4/5 digits followed by €, and clearly that doesn't mention the possibility of decimals, so I only derived that there could be decimals from your examples. Please make sure to give correct specifications.

Comment: Ok so, upon reading the thread and checking a few times, i found the issue : your original regular expression included . instead of , = that's why it didn't work! I just replaced that single character and it's working fine now : i use "-\d{2}(\,\d\d)€" and simply replace 2 by 3,4,5 as needed (because i want to target them separately. This is purely optional but i'll be glad if you explain me how you build the expression > then i can understand a bit of it :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oh, I see. This regular expression does not have much complexity -- I added an explanation, but apart from `\d` and the braces, most of it is to be taken as literal characters. I removed the parentheses as they were not needed.

Comment: Thanks, two things : 1/ changing - to + doesn't work, what should write so i can track money saving (as opposite to spendings)? 2/ i realise most of the spending are in are in the form xx.xx = what expression to use so can specifically track those starting by a certain number, for example : -5x,xx€, -6x,xx€, -7x,xx€, etc..

Comment: `+` is a character with special meaning in regex, so you need to escape it (prefix with backslash). You can just add a particular digit in your regex: it will be taken as a literal character that must appear in the input. So like: `\+5\d,\d\d€`.